# Reactive Form and dynamic checkboxes with Observables

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, angular-reactive-forms

In my application I need to create a reactive form that will contain checkboxes that will be created dynamically with the return of an **Observable**.

These chekboxes will be users that I have registered in the system, the bank should store the selected user ID, and when I display the form on the screen should show the selected users.

I'm using **Cloud Firestore** to save the data, I fetch the data from the database and saved it in the state of my application using **Ngrx**.

At any time I can have more users, so I should add and remove chekboxes from my reactive form. I have a code but it does not meet what I need, I would like a really functional logic, because I'm having trouble creating an algorithm that meets my needs.

**user.selector.ts**

```
export const getProfessionals = createSelector(
    getEntities,
    (entities): any => {
        return Object.keys(entities).
            map(id => entities[id]).
            filter(data => data.type_user === 'p');
    }
);

export const getUserSelected = createSelector(
    getEntities,
    fromRoot.getRouterState,
    (entities, router): any => {

        let selecteds = [];
        const userSelected = entities[router.state.params.id];

        if (userSelected && userSelected.type_user === 'r') {
            const professionals = Object.keys(entities)
                .map(id => entities[id])
                .filter(data => data.type_user === 'p');

            selecteds = professionals
                .map(v => userSelected.professionals.includes(v.id));
        }

        return {...userSelected, professionals: selecteds};
    }
);
```

**component.ts:**

```
user$ = this._store.select(userSelectors.getUserSelected);
professionals$ = this._store.select(userSelectors.getProfessionals);
professionalsDisplay: any[];

createForm(): void {
    this.myForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        id: new FormControl(''),
        avatar: new FormControl(''),
        type_user: new FormControl('r', Validators.required),
        subscriber: new FormControl(false),
        name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
        administrator: new FormControl(false),
        genre: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        professionals: this._formBuilder.array([]),
        password: new FormControl(''),
        passwordConfirm: new FormControl(''),
    });

    this.user$
        .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
        .subscribe((user) => {
            if (user) {
                this.myForm.patchValue(user, { emitEvent: false });
                user.professionals.forEach(value => this.usersForm.push(new FormControl(value)));
            }
        });

    this.professionals$
        .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
        .subscribe((professionals) => {
            this.professionalsDisplay = professionals;
            const values = professionals.map(v => new FormControl(false));
            this.myForm.addControl('professionals', this._formBuilder.array(values));
        });
}

get usersForm(): AbstractControl[] {
    return (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('professionals')).controls;
}
```

**component.html:**

```
<div class="h3 blue-fg">
     Which professionals do you attend?
</div>

<div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
    <div formArrayName="professionals" *ngFor="let userForm of usersForm; let i = index">
    <mat-checkbox fxFlex="100" [formControlName]="i">{{ 
     professionalsDisplay[i]?.name }}</mat-checkbox>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to save in the database the ID of the users that have been selected inside a professional array, and then when it is to display on the screen I need to show the users that are available for selection and to mark which users have been selected.

**The code problem** above is when I load the data in the form and change the checkboxes, I see that the checkboxes do not change the value of my form and do not enter the ID of the user that is selected.

Comment: First `{{ professionalsDisplay[i]?.name }}` second where are the checkboxes?

Comment: `professionalsDisplay` serves to display the names of professionals, `mat-slide-toggle` functions as a checkbox, what you do not understand?